# Asynchronous helm source without process restart

Tags: helm

I use an asynchronous helm source (a process) to query a database and want to use helm search to restrict the matches.
Currently I start helm with something like that:

```el
 (helm :sources (helm-build-async-source "query"
               :candidates-process
               #'cc-query
               :candidate-transformer
               #'helm-cc--candidates-formatter
               :action
               '(("find file" . helm-cc--action-find-files)
                 ("save results in buffer" . helm-cc--action-save-buffer)
                 ("compare" . helm-cc--action-ediff-files)))
    :buffer "*helm async source*"))
```

And `cc-query` is not much more than a `start-process`.

That works so far, however, the query is very very slow and is restarted with each pattern change. Can I avoid this restart?

Note: I use the asynchronous source, because I do not want to wait for the query to be finished.

Comment: Good question. I raised it on the [Helm Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emacs-helm/3jqLhizElFE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Helm's author](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/emacs-helm/3jqLhizElFE/GliufHvFCAAJ):

> The only way is to suspend update (`C-!`) at startup, it is  useful for example to enter a long regexp and not be annoyed by the constant update each time you enter character.  I use it also a lot when debugging.

In other words, there's no way to automatically stop updating the Helm source when the pattern is changed.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's at least something to work with. And is may be useful for other situations as well. However, I will let the question flagged unanswered for some time.